# how do I add "Home" to the left hand side of the menu bar in OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

How do I add a link to the home page - "Home" - to the left hand side of the menu bar in OpenCart?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

edit `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/header.tpl`

Find:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
```

Add right below:

```
    <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even you can add your custom menus too in the top navigation bar

edit catalog/view/theme//template/common/header.tpl

Find:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
```

Then

```
<li><a href="YOUR_LINK">Menu_Text</a></li>
```

And also you can add the Pre-defined menu like Information, Customer Service etc..

Information menu

```
  <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
      <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>">
            <?php echo $information['title']; ?></a>
      </li>
  <?php } ?>
```

Service Menu

```
 <li><?php echo $text_service; ?>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $text_return; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $sitemap; ?>"><?php echo $text_sitemap; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Extra Menu

```
<li><?php echo $text_extra; ?>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $voucher; ?>"><?php echo $text_voucher; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $affiliate; ?>"><?php echo $text_affiliate; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $special; ?>"><?php echo $text_special; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Account Menu

```
<li><?php echo $text_account; ?>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $newsletter; ?>"><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The Above mentioned Pre-defined menus are working only in the footer area, to add this in top navigation you have to do some changes in header.php

Follow this Link

[how to add Information Links in Navigation Menu in opencart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358261)

Answer (score 0):

Open Cart
Version 2.0.3.1
edit catalog/view/theme//template/common/header.tpl
Find
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`
And then under the above put
`<li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>`
works a traet.