# how to add Information Links in Navigation Menu in opencart?

Tags: php, menu, navigation, opencart

I got this error when trying to add the information Link in `open cart` top **navigation menu**

```
Notice: 
Undefined variable: 
         informations in 
         C:\Inetpub\vhosts\fima.net.in\httpdocs\catalog\view\theme\fima\template\common\header.tpl on line 229
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
         C:\Inetpub\vhosts\fima.net.in\httpdocs\catalog\view\theme\fima\template\common\header.tpl on line 229
```

Code:

```
<ul>
     <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
       <li>
          <a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>">
             <?php echo $information['title']; ?>
          </a>
      </li>
     <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Finally i found the solution

include this below lines in the header.php under controller directory

```
    $this->data['text_information'] = $this->language->get('text_information');
    $this->data['text_service'] = $this->language->get('text_service');
    $this->data['text_extra'] = $this->language->get('text_extra');
    $this->data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact');
    $this->data['text_return'] = $this->language->get('text_return');
    $this->data['text_sitemap'] = $this->language->get('text_sitemap');
    $this->data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
    $this->data['text_voucher'] = $this->language->get('text_voucher');
    $this->data['text_affiliate'] = $this->language->get('text_affiliate');
    $this->data['text_special'] = $this->language->get('text_special');
    $this->data['text_account'] = $this->language->get('text_account');
    $this->data['text_order'] = $this->language->get('text_order');
    $this->data['text_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('text_wishlist');
    $this->data['text_newsletter'] = $this->language->get('text_newsletter');

    $this->load->model('catalog/information');

    $this->data['informations'] = array();

    foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
        if ($result['bottom']) {
            $this->data['informations'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'href'  => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    $this->data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
    $this->data['return'] = $this->url->link('account/return/insert', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['sitemap'] = $this->url->link('information/sitemap');
    $this->data['manufacturer'] = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer');
    $this->data['voucher'] = $this->url->link('account/voucher', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['affiliate'] = $this->url->link('affiliate/account', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['special'] = $this->url->link('product/special');
    $this->data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['newsletter'] = $this->url->link('account/newsletter', '', 'SSL');
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after all this time, where did you add this? I've added it pretty much everywhere in my header.tpl file and I get the same error as you did. Thanks

Comment: Not in header.tpl @DaveWoodhall it is header.php